# Need to show dollar sign only in first row of MS Access report

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a report for my job that I'm going to need to produce for hundreds of individuals. I would like to be able to insert a dollar sign only in the first row of an access report that is driven by a crosstab query. I have found a solution online that seems like it will work using a label and a text box and code similar to:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Me.lblDollarSign.Visible = Me.txtCount = 1
End Sub
```

setting txtCount = 1 and running it as a running sum so it's 2, 3, 4 in subsequent rows.

I found the idea on this site: https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/re-change-format-of-just-the-first-detail-row-of-a-report-in-access.2927741/ but it just won't work.

Does anybody have any other suggestions or possible explanations why my solution isn't working? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what version of Access is this. is there a unique identifier like an ID column included in the results set?

Comment: Most recent version of MS Access as far as I know. No unique identifier - I need to dynamically re-sort the report values based on a calculated comment, so I figured using a label that sits in the first row and increments would work, but I just can't get the solution cited above to work.

Comment: Some Report events are only triggered on the Print Preview, not on the Report View.  Format event is one of those I think.  Does your solution work in Print Preview?

Comment: Oh my God, it does work in Print Preview... I didn't even think to check that. Thank you so much, I think that should be sufficient. I can't even begin to express my appreciation - thank you so so so so much.

Comment: @DavidMcCormack Glad it works.  Formal documentation is often either incomplete or cryptic for these kind of details.  I recommend always adding `Debug.Print` statements for debugging report (and form) events to 1) verify they are even firing and 2) being able to inspect what order they fire and 3) how often they fire, etc.  Access events (and Reports in general) do not always do what you'd think intuitively.  A web search for "access detail format" shows many pages.

Answer (score 1):

Create a textbox with expression: `="$"`.

Set HideDuplicates property to Yes.

This will work in Print and Report views.

No VBA required.

However, if report has Grouping setup, the character will show once in each group.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a very easy solution to this problem.

If you put an invisible item number in your report you can reference that field in your VBA code.  In the following example I am putting the dollar sign on the Equity Investment and EBITDA fields - first record only.

```
Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
If Me.txtItemNumber = 1 Then
Me.Equity_Investment.Format = "Currency"
Me.EBITDA.Format = "Currency"

Else

Me.Equity_Investment.Format = "Standard"

Me.EBITDA.Format = "Standard"
End If
End Sub
```